# "I have been injured in the last two months" vs "...for the last two months" vs "...the last two months"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-meaning, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Do you think all three of these sentences correct and interchangeable? I am not sure if they are all correct.

- "I have been injured in the last two months"
- "I have been injured for the last two months"
- "I have been injured the last two months"

Context: I was injured two months ago, and I am still injured.

Comment: They are not all interchangeable. The first one states that you suffered an injury at some time during the last two months (but may have since recovered). The second says that you had an injury two months ago and are still suffering from the effects of it. It is better to  use _for_ than to leave it out, as in your third version.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. Isn't it wrong to specify the time after the perfect tense though?

Comment: **The verb injured is probably not right here**. I have been bed-ridden or excused from work for the last two month **due to injury**. In English, the verb injured is usually associated an event, and it not used in the progressive tense in medical contexts. Or: due to injuries I sustained three months ago.,

Comment: correction: associated with an event and is not used

Comment: @Lambie “injured” is an adjective in that sentence.

Comment: An adjective? have been + past participle is the present perfect, a verb tense. As you can see, I have 2 agrees....An adjective would be: The **injured man** limped down the street looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are correct but have different meanings.

The first means "An injury occurred between now and two months ago".  It might be that you have fully recovered, or you might still be suffering.  The injury could have occurred 8 weeks ago, or it could have occurred yesterday. It probably refers to more serious injuries that affect your health and safety. You are more likely to see this as a question:

> Have you been injured in the last two months?

The second means that you have been suffering from an injury for a period of two months.  This is usually used for sporting injuries, which might not be very severe, can affect your performance at a sport.

> I've been injured for the last two months, so I've not been able to play football.

In your situation: "I was injured two months ago, and I am still injured."  you would tell someone "I've been injured for two months". But if someone asked "Have you been injured in the last two months" you would reply "Yes".

The last is a slightly non-standard form of the second, with a noun phrase acting as a modifier instead of a standard prepositional phrase. It would be quite common in speech.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the first sentence I gave wouldn't mean what you said because I used the present perfect continous tense in it. Isn't it wrong to specify the time after after the perfect tense? Can I use, "in," only in negative words when I want to mean, "for"? In the first sentence,  I wanted to mean the same thing as the sentence 2.

Comment: Not the present perfect continuous.  Just the present perfect "have been +adj"  You can use "in" with present perfect to refer to a state resulting from an event that occurred in the past in some time interval leading up to the present.  "I have played tennis in the last year" is correct, but "I have played tennis on January 28th" is wrong.

Comment: So the first sentence I gave and the second one can have the same meaning then.

Comment: No.  They have different meanings, as explained in my answer.

Comment: You said it meant the injury had happened between now and two moths ago. So this includes two months ago.

Comment: I don't think the verb injured is what is meant here. I think it's I sustained an injury [three months ago]. I have been injured playing football, but that is not like this sentence here.

Comment: I still don’t understand why the first sentence and the second sentence don’t mean the same. Wouldn’t we say, “I was injured in the last two months” instead to mean an injury occurred between now and two months ago?

Comment: "I have (watched television/visited London/sustained an injury) in the last two months" means that one or more instances of that experience have happened to you during that time period. "...For the last two months" means that the experience has lasted for the whole time.

Comment: @KateBunting But I use “injured” as an adjective in my sentence. I don’t use it to mean an incident of getting injured, but to mean a state of being an injured person.

Comment: As Lambie commented above, _injured_ is not the best word to convey that meaning. "I have been injured" means "Something has happened to me that caused an injury". "I have been injured for two months" would be understood to mean "I was injured two months ago and have not yet recovered", but it is not the best way to express it. Better to say something like "I have been disabled following an injury."

Comment: This use of "injured" is quite common when speaking of sports injuries.  Someone who has pulled a muscle is not "disabled" but they might count themselves as "disabled" if they are unable to participate in sport.